# What is Virtual Folder in Sdl tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Can any one help me regarding Virtual Folder in Sdl Tridion.

1. what is virtual folder in Sdl-Tridion ?
2. How to create Virtual folder ?
3. What are its uses ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are basically asking for a tutorial, and your question doesn't show many efforts to find one. See [ask] to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Folder has results from a data store or a custom index, and presents them visually in the format in which folder views are presented.

Virtual Folder thread answered [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/what-is-virtual-folder-in-sdl-tridion)